# How to respond with dynamic options in IBM Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

My webhook returns an array of elements. I need to make IBM Watson Assistant respond with those elements as options to the users.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is the number of returned options fix or changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@data_henrik response was very helpful but it was little vague. So, I thought to post my own answer. I made some changes in my function so that the result it returns matches the options format just like in the image below.

[image]

And just as @data_henrik suggested, I stored that result in a context variable named **myOptions** and used it like :

```
<? output.generic.addAll($myOptions) ?>
```

Comment: Not sure what your answer adds. I pointed to the official format and showed how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON structure for an IBM Watson Assistant [answer with options is documented](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-add-option). You already mentioned that your webhook returned an array of elements. It would need to match that structure.

Now, in your dialog you would need to add that options array **myOptionsArray** to your output. Assuming the array data is stored in the variable **myvar**, use something like this:

```
<? output.generic.addAll($myvar.myOptionsArray) ?>
```

The generic refers to the [generic JSON output format](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json) - in contrast to the integrations JSON format. The above expression could be placed in a response or in some intermediate assignment. It might need some experimenting but works...

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik, that was very helpful.

Comment: Also see this blog post: https://medium.com/ibm-watson/how-to-dynamically-add-response-options-to-dialog-nodes-in-watson-assistant-e14c5e08beca